# Updating OpenSSL on OSx 10.8.3 Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

Okay, so I have a fresh install and a clean slate...

**What is the proper way to update OpenSSL from scratch on OSx 10.8.3?**

Nothing is installed yet, but after I can get OpenSSL updated to v1+ I usually go with the standard: RailsInstaller.org ..... or should I be doing Homebrew/RVM first to setup rails?

Things like http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/ have issues without the updated OpenSSL and their recommendations don't seem to to the trick. http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

I have tried many ways without luck. Lot's of discussion/suggestions out there but would like to get it right one the first time without messing anything else up this time. Is it maybe that there is a line that requires sudo? If we can get a solid answer I'd like to get it out there to the rest of the community.

System: 15" MacBookPro Retina (2013) with OSx 10.8.3 Mountain Lion

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party...but the following non-rvm approach works for me:

- pull and unzip sources from http://openssl.org/
- ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc
- make
- make test
- sudo make install

This will put the executable in `/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl`, so add this to your path (e.g. in .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/ssl/bin:$PATH"
```

And you may need to recompile ruby in order to pick up the changes.

Comment: in make test, i get test/recipes/90-test_async.t failed "Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100) Failed 1/1 subtests"

Answer (score 0):

Use RVM 1.19:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable
```

It will use existing package manager (fallback to Homebrew), install all requirements for ruby and ruby itself, right now it is MRI Ruby `2.0.0-p0`

Follow instructions given from the installer, then:

```
rvm use ruby
ruby -v
```

Comment: It seems I still run into the same issue.  OpenSSL is "installed" but not active?  Thank you for the help.<br/>

   * https://gist.github.com/TheEricMiller/b1eba715f07641f1b624<br/>

1) Installed Xcode Apple "Command Line Tools"
 ~ AppStore Xcode > "Preferences" > "Command Line Tools"  ~or~ via http://Connect.Apple.com
2) Installed Homebrew ~ http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/
 ~ $ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
 ~ $ brew doctor
 ~ $ brew update
3) Installed RVM ~ https://rvm.io/
 ~ $ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable

Comment: It seems like the system version is overriding brew / rvm... I can get terminal to show updated version if I move like so: $ sudo mv /usr/bin/openssl /usr/bin/zz-openssl-bak  $ brew link openssl